# How to improve the speed to run so file in Kotlin?

Tags: android, performance, opencv, java-native-interface, face-recognition

everyone. I have two face detection project. One is java project and another is kotlin.
Both two projects use mlkit for face detection and opencv c++ engine for face recognition.
The c++ engine is exactly same in two project. After building two projects, when I run them, their c++ engine runtime is different. Java project is faster than Kotlin.

```
JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL
FACE_ENGINE_METHOD(nativeExtractLiveFeature)(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
        jobject bmp, jint left, jint top, jint right, jint bottom,
        jfloatArray landmarksX, jfloatArray landmarksY, jfloatArray features)
```

This is c++ code what I wanna call. I import it into projects like this.

```
@Keep
private native static float nativeExtractLiveFeature(Bitmap bmp, int leftFace, int topFace, int rightFace, int bottomFace, float[] landmarksX, float[] landmarksY, float[] features);    // java

@Keep
private external fun nativeExtractLiveFeature(bmp: Bitmap, leftFace: Int, topFace: Int, rightFace: Int, bottomFace: Int, landmarksX: FloatArray, landmarksY: FloatArray, features: FloatArray): Float   //kotlin
```

Java project is almost 2 times faster than Kotlin now. Please let me know what causes it.
I need to improve the speed of Kotlin project as fast as Java one. I wanna know any possible way.
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see how i save the file and then open it then find the face. below is the code for how:

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Path to video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

# Used as counter variable
count = 1

# checks whether frames were extracted
success = 1

while success:

    #  get each frame from the video
    # '_' is a flag to show if the frame was read correctly or not
    # 'img' is the frame itself
    _, image = cap.read()

    if count <= 1:
        # Saves the frames with frame-count
        cv2.imwrite("frame_%d.jpg" % count, image)

        count += 1

    if count == 2:
        count = 1
        frame = cv2.imread('frame_1.jpg')
        
        # use the frames below


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```